# Windows Sharepoint Services Login Problem

Tags: windows, sharepoint, login, service, wss

I am wanting to try out Windows Sharepoint Services on my Windows 2008 Box at home.

The Windows 2008 Server is a domain controller.

I have installed IIS 7, Active Directory, SQL 2008 Standard and downloaded Windows Sharepoint Services 3 SP2.

I setup first hostnames in the DNS Server called sharepoint, I went into IIS7 created a website using the hostname sharepoint and sharepoint.domain.local worked fine.

Deleted the Website from IIS

Then I installed Windows Sharepoint Services

configured it and created a Sharepoint site called Sharepoint configured the hostname to be sharepoint.domain.local

Configured a site for sharepoint.domain.local which is a Sharepoint Wiki template

Now when I go to access either sharepoint.domain.local its asks for a username and password I have tried everything from username password for the windows login to domain\username and and password.

it brings up the login box 3 times as the username password it wrong then after the third attempt it displays a white screen.

How do I fix this.

Thanks

Matthew

Comment: From where are you connecting ? local server browser ? domain joined computer ? workgroup ?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using IE to connect to the site. Try using a different browser like firefox and see if that allows you to connect

Answer (score 2):

You could be running into a local loopback problem. The problem occurs when the website uses Integrated authentication, and has a name that is mapped back to the local loopback address.

The fix is to go to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

Add a new DWORD value named DisableLoopbackCheck and give it a value of 1. After setting the value reboot your server.

For further details, check out this KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Answer (score 0):

The site must be in the local intranet zone to use integrated authentication (from a domain joined computer)

Comment: I am connecting from the Servers its on which is installed on a Domain Controller.

I have added it to the local intranet zone on the server. and it still asks for a username and password. but I can access the Sharepoint Central Admin site without any username or password.

Comment: What are the authentication methods allowed on the IIS site ?

Comment: how do I check the  authentication methods allowed on the IIS site ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you are using Active Directory and set up a user to "Change password on next login", it will prompt for a password but not log in.  It will try three times and then simply display a white screen and nothing.  *Simply set the user to Password never expires, and the problem goes away* (at least for us it did).  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You realize some companies have a mandatory (by regulation, policy, or audit requirement) password expiration timeframe, right? Disabling password expiration in such an environment is often grounds for termination...

Comment: He wasn't referring to removing the password expiration, just if "Change password on next login" is checked.  They are two different settings.